# Observable function ignoring code "return defer"

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, observable

recently I am working with Angular 11, I am trying to do a function that checks if the account is allowed to do an action however I have to get it whenever there is a change in the SAS Token, that said, I did the functions below

```
      /**
   *Verify if SAS has permissions
   * @param sasUri Sas address
   * @param permissions The permissions to verify
   * @returns Boolean Value
   */
  async hasPermissions(sasUri: string, permissions: SASInformationPermission[]): Promise<boolean> {
    const permissionAccount = await this.getSASUriInformation(sasUri).toPromise();
    return permissions.every((permission) => {
      permissionAccount.signedPermissions.includes(permission);
    });
  }

  /**
   * Get validation of action permission
   * @param sasUri Sas address
   * @param action The action to check
   * @returns Boolean value
   */
  hasActionPermission(sasUri: string, action: Action): Observable<boolean> {
    return defer(async () => {
      let permission: SASInformationPermission[];
      if (action === 'upload') {
        permission = [
          SASInformationPermission.Read,
          SASInformationPermission.List,
          SASInformationPermission.Write,
        ];
      } else {
        permission = [SASInformationPermission.List, SASInformationPermission.Read];
      }

      return await this.hasPermissions(sasUri, permission);
    });
  }
```

the "hasPermissions" function takes and checks if the SAS has access to the action that is passed by parameter and the "HasActionPermission" function calls the above function to have a Boolean value

the function "HasActionPermission" simply does not enter the "return defer" what can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embrace observables.  You seem to be going back and forth between observables and promises, but this seems entirely unnecessary.  Feel free to call `toPromise()` after `hasActionPermissions()` is called.

Here's an rxjs-only rewrite:

```
hasPermissions(sasUri: string, permissions: SASInformationPermission[]): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.getSASUriInformation(sasUri).pipe(
    map(acct => permissions.every(x => acct.signedPermissions.includes(x)))
  );
}

hasActionPermission(sasUri: string, action: Action): Observable<boolean> {
  const permission: SASInformationPermission[] = (action === 'upload') 
    ? [SASInformationPermission.Read, SASInformationPermission.List, SASInformationPermission.Write]
    : [SASInformationPermission.List, SASInformationPermission.Read];
    
  return this.hasPermissions(sasUri, permission);
}
```

It's a lot cleaner, and it will be cold until you call `subscribe()` or `toPromise()`, no need for `defer()`.